concrete slab for shed base
I am about to order 12x20 shed kit and need to start building concrete slab. Can I throw 3inch gravel and 2inch concrete on top of the gravel? Or this wouldn't last long? I can pour all concrete but it is going to cost a lot, So I am looking for cheaper option by putting gravel under neath.

Depending on what you are putting in the shed, there may be other options. For example, a floating deck doesn't require any concrete work at all. I am extremely far from an expert on concrete but I don't think 2"will hold up very well.

I see, shed is for regular use, putting shovels and other backyard stuff

In my community, a shed such as yours would require a ratwall and 4" of base.

I am stunned. Is the footprint really 12 feet by 20 feet? That's huge. Surely you've noticed sidewalks with 4" pours and rebar reinforcement can barely tolerate even geologic movement and normal tree roots without becoming rubble in about 5-10 years. I echo others' suggestion to use in-situ piers. The other added advantage is that if the foundation starts to slope, it's much easier to remedy this with a pier system (either poured or precast) by jacking directly on a strong timber you added rather than the shed itself.

shed size 12x20.

If you're buying bags of gravel and concrete mix, you'll find that they are around the same price. Gravel may even be a little more expensive than the equivalent weight of concrete mix. There's no logical reason for this except market pressures.
You may save money by getting a bulk load of crushed stone delivered, depending on the delivery charge.
Why not go for the standard 4-inch slab as most people recommend, because your proposed slab won't cost less and might cost more.

I am hesitant to put 4inch concrete on the mud, Don't I need gravel under it, or just putting concrete mix directly on the mud is fine?

@lkqWRHL23O You didn't mention mud! A concrete slab can be poured directly onto dry, "undisturbed" soil, which means soil from which the upper organic layer (grass/loam/etc) has been scraped off without digging into the hard-packed soil below. Thorough mechanical compaction of lightly disturbed dry soil is also acceptable. If you have mud or a dug-up yard, compaction topped by crushed stone, then a 4-inch slab should be OK. A thinner slab is too easy to crack from concentrated weight on a less-than-firm substrate.

thank you so much!

Heck, even a delivery charge for GAB can be worth not having to schlep bags of material from the depot to your vehicle, and then from the vehicle to the work site.

2" concrete is not a good idea. 4" is the usual standard. That calculates to:

80 cubic feet
3 cubic yards
133 80 lb. bags

Plus you need a base under it (not sure what's best - I see a variety of options - gravel, crushed rock, crushed old concrete, etc.)
Doing that yourself (i.e., bags of mix + a small mixer on-site) is going to be a lot of mixing and pouring. Alternatively, you could do the digging and framing yourself, then get a truckload of base delivered and spread it out yourself and compact it. And then get a truck to deliver 3 yards of concrete and spread it out and finish it yourself.
But another option is a floating deck. This is basically deck blocks, like these from Home Depot:

plus pressure treated lumber to frame it and deck boards across the top. This has a some big advantages over concrete:

Much easier to DIY
Does not have to all get done in one day
If your ground is sloped then you don't have to do as much prep work, just cut 4x4s to fit in the blocks to support the frame at a level consistent height

On the other hand, while a floating deck is quite sturdy, it is not the same as a real foundation. For storing tools and doing some manual labor inside it will do just fine. If your shed will actually be used as a garage it may not work as well.

why not pour piers as middle option between real 4in slab and deck blocks?

When you use deck blocks (or piers), you have the added complication of having to deal with sizing beams and joists, and likely raising the FF of the shed to need a ramp or steps.

Sizing not a big deal, provided it is "just a shed" and not a garage. But yes, any deck (floating or not) will mean a couple of steps or a small ramp.
